# CSS Border-Radius Shows Parent's Style

Tags: html, css, liferay

I have a button on top of a div with a background colour, a box-shadow, and a border. The button has border-radius corners and the top div's background colour and other styles show through.

Easiest way to explain is this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/wCppN/1/

### HTML:

```
<div class="journal-content-article">
    <div class="button">
        Hello Button
    </div>
</div>

<div class="journal-content-article">
    Normal article with white background.
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.journal-content-article {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px darkgrey;
}

.button {
    border-radius: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

I want to be able to leave the 'normal article' div as is, but be able to remove the white background, the black border, and the box-shadow from the 'button'.

This is being done through Liferay web content so I'm limited to what HTML changes can be made. Only any HTML inside the div 'journal-content-article' can be changed, and can't add additional classes to that div or any parent div.

I also can't change the 'normal article' div contents as the users (no CSS/HTML experience) have to type that in.

Any ideas on how to achieve this, or am I forced to use Javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think you can achieve this without javascript.Because `button` is the only element inside the `div` so `div` has the same height and width as button

Comment: @tbigby It is a bit confusing as to what you are trying to achieve.Can you simplify it a bit?

Comment: You can't edit the css for `.journal-content-article`?

Comment: I assume you also can't do <div class="journal-content-article" id="something"> ?

Comment: @freebird - Please see fredsbend's solution (http://jsfiddle.net/wCppN/7/) which shows the desired result. I just can't add the div '.myClass'. Essentially it's a CSS parent depending on child scenario, which I understand can't be done from other Stack Overflow questions. Just wondering if there was a way to override or mask out the style from the parent element in certain cases.

Comment: @fredsbend - Yes I can edit the CSS for '.journal-content-article' (I can edit any CSS actually), just that I can't enforce the HTML inside a '.journal-content-article' for a normal article. I can enforce the HTML inside the '.journal-content-article' for the button.

Comment: @Joe - You're right, I can't add an ID, class, or any other attribute to '.journal-content-article'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can override .journal-content-article's style without either doing something like fredsbend suggests, or being able to edit the div itself.  You can effectively override the white background, something like this:

```
div class="journal-content-article">
   <div class="journal-content-inside">
    <div class="button">
        Hello Button
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

.journal-content-inside {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: none;
 }
```

However that doesn't fix the border and box-shadow problem.  I don't know that those really are fixable without javascript or other means of editing outside the div.

Comment: I agree, and I tried out the background concept in testing. Although in this case it is complicated by the page background actually being a tiled image! As you say, that still leaves the shadow and border. I was hoping someone might have a fancy clipping solution or something? Or like, `underflow: hidden` (if that CSS actually existed).

Comment: Accepting this answer - the first answer to confirm it doesn't seem to be possible to do this without changing HTML or using Javascript. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

http://jsfiddle.net/wCppN/7/

```
<div class="journal-content-article">
    <div class="button">Hello Button</div>
</div>
<div class="journal-content-article">
    <div class="myClass">Normal article with white background.</div>
</div>

.journal-content-article {
    margin: 20px 20px;
    width: 150px;
}
.myClass {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px darkgrey;
}
```

Comment: Add `overflow:hidden` to `.myClass` and use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCppN/10/)

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! Unfortunately I can't change the second article (where you've put a myClass div), as the end users will be creating hundreds of those articles, and would have to add that div themselves in the Liferay rich editor source code.

Comment: If you are ok with javascript I will work on something that way. With a simple code you should be able to target all `.journal-content-article` and `.button` divs then apply the necessary styles.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid the Javascript if possible, but yes, my next plan was to get the parent of the 'button' class and add a new class to the parent dynamically. Since it's Liferay I'll write something up in Liferay's AlloyUI framework, so please don't stress about writing a Javascript for this!

Answer (score 0):

One method that may help someone else, would be to set a negative margin on the button:

```
.button {
    margin: -10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wCppN/11/

This makes the button larger than the border and shadow, and with `overflow: hidden` off, covers up the problem.

However it has the disadvantage that the button becomes bigger than you want. In some designs that might be fine, but we have a box/column structure and just -2px of margin looks too badly out of alignment for me to use this (I'm a perfectionist)!

It might help someone else though!